# Multiple SSH chaining (tsocks, socksify, proxycommand, etc. )

Tags: linux, fedora, ssh-tunneling

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTOvt.png

Goal: you need to reach "Server B" from the Client "directly" with SSH, SCP.

"Server B" is next to "Server A". E.g.: they're on the same subnet, but only "Server A" is reachable from the Internet -> so "Server B" is only indirectly accessible.


I know how to use tsocks:

install tsocks

```
yum install tsocks
```

configure it [by default there is no config file..]

```
vim /etc/tsocks.conf
server = 127.0.0.1
server_port = 4000
```

create the ssh tunnel

```
ssh -v -fND localhost:4000 USERNAME@SERVER-A
```

check that if it's created

```
ps aux | fgrep -i ssh
USER      8894  0.0  0.0   9780   708 ?        Ss   11:58   0:00 ssh -v -fND localhost:4000 USERNAME@SERVER-A
netstat -tulpn | fgrep -i ssh
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4000              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      8894/ssh
```

how to use tsocks

```
tsocks ssh root@SERVER-B
```

kill the ssh tunnel

```
kill `pgrep -f 'D localhost:4000'`
```

The whole thing is fully OK to me. Fine.

The Question: How can I use multiple ssh tunnels with e.g.: tsocks?
I mean I have to use several ssh tunnels (on different ports of course).
How can I set e.g.: tsocks to "memorize" several ssh tunnels (ports)?

The "/etc/tsocks.conf" file only allows one server, that's ok, because If I ssh tunnel to somewhere I have to go through 127.0.0.1, but I need more ports, because 1 port = 1 ssh tunnel. Several ssh tunnels can't bind to 1 port.
I'm using Fedora 14 for "Desktop PC"

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tsocks` allows multiple SOCKS services, you set it up to use a different SOCKS service (i.e. different `ssh -D` listening on a different port) for each desired target. `man tsocks.conf` for more details.

assuming `/etc/tsocks.conf` containing:

```
path {
    server = localhost
    server_port = 1081
    reaches = <ip-address-of-server-b>/32
    }
path {
    server = localhost
    server_port = 1082
    reaches = <ip-address-of-server-d>/32
    }
```

Then you would run

```
ssh -fND :1081 server-a & sleep 1 ; tsocks ssh server-b
ssh -fND :1082 server-c & sleep 1 ; tsocks ssh server-d
```