# ssh tunnel on ssh tunnel between Windows and two Linux machines

Tags: linux, ssh, windows, tunneling

I have the following configuration and want to establish a tunnel on a tunnel.
I read already the following topic:
[How to put a tunnel in a tunnel?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28270/how-to-put-a-tunnel-in-a-tunnel)

My configuration:

```
Notebook --> Linux Server A --> Linux Server B
```

Notebook: Windows XP with putty
Linux Server A and B: Ubuntu 10.10

I have a ssh connection with a tunnel from my notebook via putty to Server A.
Now I want to establish a tunnel from Server A to B, so that I can connect with an IDE directly to my jboss on Server B.

This is the command I tried on Server A to establish a tunnel:

```
ssh -t -L 8080:localhost:8080 Server B -p 8822
```

This won't work.

Anybody an idea how to establish a working tunnel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is called "ssh multi-hop". It is quite possible to do this transparently, using the ProxyCommand directive in `.ssh/config` (or an equivalent config option in PuTTY, or what-have-you):

```
Host linux-server-b
  ProxyCommand ssh -q linux-server-a nc -q0 linux-server-b 22
```

What this does, when you try to connect to `linux-server-b`:

- opens a SSH connection to `linux-server-a`
- runs `netcat` there, and opens a TCP connection to `linux-server-b`
- forwards this connection back to you

This way, you can use all the features of SSH, as if you were connected to `linux-server-b` directly; you can even chain multiple hops together (server A to server B to server C to server D ...)

See also:

- http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html
- https://superuser.com/a/107681/2249

Comment: Since this was posted, ssh evolved to include a `-W <host>:<port>` option, that avoids the use of `nc`.

Comment: @AlexStragies: Good point. I'll check when this was added and edit. Oh, and there's now `-J` (or `ProxyJump`) which makes this even easier; but that's only in OpenSSH 7.3 and up.