# how to specify the forwarding port when using multiple tsocks services?

Tags: linux, wget, ssh-tunneling, socks

According to the answer of this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13633/multiple-ssh-chaining-tsocks-socksify-proxycommand-etc), I have my `/etc/tsocks.conf` containing these lines:

```
path {
server = localhost
server_port = 1081
reaches = <ip-address-of-server-b>/32
}
path {
server = localhost
server_port = 1082
reaches = <ip-address-of-server-d>/32
}
```

and I have run these two commands:

```
ssh -fND :1081 server-a
ssh -fND :1082 server-b
```

Now I want to use `tsocks` to do a wget of a page first using the socks'
service listening to 1081 port and then using the other one listening to 1082 port. If I had only one service I know that I can do that through this command:

```
tsocks wget http://www.google.com
```

Now that I have more than one `tsocks` services how can I do that? Can I provide for example the forwarding port through an option? I can't find something in the man pages of `tsocks`. I want something like that:

```
tsocks --forwarding_port=1081 wget http://www.google.com
tsocks --forwarding_port=1082 wget http://www.google.com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using two different configuration files for tsocks?

According to [this manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tsocks), tsocks will read its configuration from the file specified in the `TSOCKS_CONF_FILE` environment variable. So you could split your `tsocks.conf` to `tsocks.1081.conf` and `tsocks.1082.conf` and then do something like this (bash syntax):

```
$ TSOCKS_CONF_FILE=/path/to/tsocks.1081.conf tsocks wget http://www.google.com
$ TSOCKS_CONF_FILE=/path/to/tsocks.1082.conf tsocks wget http://www.google.com
```

**Note:** The manpage has a typo and lists the environment variable as `TSOCKS_CONFFILE` - missing an underscore.

Comment: btw, the question you mention seems to be for a different case than yours. They want to use tsocks for reaching different servers through different ssh tunnels. You want to make tsocks reach the same server through a specific ssh tunnel.

Comment: yes, I just want to make many ssh tunnels to download a batch of URLs . I have splited the URLs set to different downloader instances, and I want each downloader instance to use a different socks' proxy.. :) I will check your answer right now!

Comment: yes ok!! :) it works if you replace the `TSOCKS_CONFFILE` with `TSOCKS_CONF_FILE`. It should be a typo in the manual.. For more information you can see this page:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=702864

Thank you very much for the answer! :) Please update your answer with the right configuration file token!